# C: pass to function an array of structure pointers to be reallocated dynamically each time

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I should dynamically allocate an array of pointers to structure, passing from time to time parameters for a single structure.
sorry if I can not explain, here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


typedef struct _DROP_DOWN_MENU_LABELS
{
    char *title;
    char **items;
} MenuLabels;

MenuLabels ** ml_init(void)
{
    MenuLabels **ml;
    ml=(MenuLabels **)calloc(2,sizeof(MenuLabels*));
    ml[1]=NULL;
    return ml;
}



void addit(MenuLabels **mlabels, char *title, char *elems,...)
{

    int j;
    for (j=0; mlabels[j]!=NULL ; j++ );
    printf("\n\nCHECK:MenuLabels has %d menu",j);

    mlabels=(MenuLabels **)realloc(mlabels,(j+2)*sizeof(MenuLabels*));

    mlabels[j]=(MenuLabels *)malloc(1*sizeof(MenuLabels));

    mlabels[j+1]=NULL;




    mlabels[j]->title=title;

    /*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
    int i=0;
    char **mitems=NULL;
    mitems=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    mitems[i]=elems;

    va_list argP;
    va_start(argP, elems);

    char *p;
    for (i=1; ((p=va_arg(argP,char*)) !=NULL) ; i++ )
    {
        mitems=(char **)realloc(mitems,(i+1)*sizeof(char*));
        mitems[i]=p;
    }

    if (!p)
    {
        mitems=(char **)realloc(mitems,(i+1)*sizeof(char*));
        mitems[i]=NULL;
    }

    va_end(argP);
    /*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/

    mlabels[j]->items=mitems;
}



int main()
{
    MenuLabels **ml;
    ml=ml_init();
    addit(ml,"FILE","new","open","save","backup","print","setup","exit",NULL);
    addit(ml,"AFILE","Anew","Asave","Abackup","Aexit",NULL);
    addit(ml,"BFILE","Bnew","Bopen","Bsave","Bprint","Bexit",NULL);

    free(ml);

    fprintf(stdout,"\n\033[1;91m***END***\033[0m\n");
    return 0;
}
```

starting the program seems to be executed without errors:

```
CHECK:MenuLabels has 0 menu

CHECK:MenuLabels has 1 menu

CHECK:MenuLabels has 2 menu
***END***

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.001 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

but checking with valgrind:

```
==5572== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5572== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5572== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5572== Command: ./prove
==5572== 


==5572== Invalid read of size 8
==5572==    at 0x400812: addit (main.c:26)
==5572==    by 0x400B27: main (main.c:75)
==5572==  Address 0x5204040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==5572==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5572==    by 0x400855: addit (main.c:29)
==5572==    by 0x400AF1: main (main.c:74)
==5572==  Block was alloc'd at
==5572==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5572==    by 0x40075C: ml_init (main.c:15)
==5572==    by 0x400AB0: main (main.c:73)
==5572== 
CHECK:MenuLabels has 0 menu

==5572== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==5572==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5572==    by 0x400855: addit (main.c:29)
==5572==    by 0x400B27: main (main.c:75)
==5572==  Address 0x5204040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==5572==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5572==    by 0x400855: addit (main.c:29)
==5572==    by 0x400AF1: main (main.c:74)
==5572==  Block was alloc'd at
==5572==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5572==    by 0x40075C: ml_init (main.c:15)
==5572==    by 0x400AB0: main (main.c:73)
==5572== 
==5572== Invalid write of size 8
==5572==    at 0x400882: addit (main.c:31)
==5572==    by 0x400B27: main (main.c:75)
==5572==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==5572== 
==5572== 
==5572== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==5572==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==5572==    at 0x400882: addit (main.c:31)
==5572==    by 0x400B27: main (main.c:75)
==5572==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==5572==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==5572==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==5572==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==5572==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
CHECK:MenuLabels has 0 menu==5572== 
==5572== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5572==     in use at exit: 112 bytes in 4 blocks
==5572==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 10 frees, 1,392 bytes allocated
==5572== 
==5572== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 4
==5572==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5572==    by 0x400881: addit (main.c:31)
==5572==    by 0x400B27: main (main.c:75)
==5572== 
==5572== 96 (16 direct, 80 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
==5572==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5572==    by 0x400855: addit (main.c:29)
==5572==    by 0x400AF1: main (main.c:74)
==5572== 
==5572== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5572==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 2 blocks
==5572==    indirectly lost: 80 bytes in 2 blocks
==5572==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5572==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5572==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5572== 
==5572== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5572== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
./run_valgrind: riga 4:  5572 Errore di segmentazione (core dump creato) valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --tool=memcheck ./prove
```

and in fact if I try to extract any value from ml at the end (eg ml[n]-> title) it goes into segmentation fault

what am I doing wrong? thank you all in advance

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but symbols beginning with a leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter (like `_DROP_DOWN_MENU_LABELS` in your code) are reserved for the compiler and standard library in all scopes.

Comment: Your error trace refers to line 29, in the middle of the code you've left out.  Try looking there.  Alternately, provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one problem:

```
char **mitems;
// ... assuming there's a mitems = malloc(...) or similar here...
mlabels[j]->items=mitems;
free(mitems);
```

Here you have a a pointer, you make it point to some memory you allocate, you copy the pointer (so you have two pointers pointing *to the same memory*) and then you free the memory that both pointers are pointing to.

The `free` call makes not only `mitems` invalid, but also `mlabels[j]->items`.

Comment: ok thanks, mitems is rightly allocated, even if I remove free (mitems); the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

I solved ... here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


typedef struct s_drop_down_menu_labels
{
    char *title;
    char **items;
} MenuLabels;

MenuLabels ** ml_init(void)
{
    MenuLabels **ml;
    ml=(MenuLabels **)calloc(2,sizeof(MenuLabels*));
    ml[1]=NULL;
    return ml;
}



void addit(MenuLabels ***mlabels, char *title, char *elems,...)
{
    int j;
    for (j=0; (*mlabels)[j]!=NULL ; j++ );
    printf("\n\nCHECK:MenuLabels has %d menu",j);

    *mlabels=(MenuLabels **)realloc(*mlabels,(j+2)*sizeof(MenuLabels*));
    (*mlabels)[j]=(MenuLabels *)malloc(1*sizeof(MenuLabels));
    (*mlabels)[j+1]=NULL;

    (*mlabels)[j]->title=title;

    /*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
    int i=0;
    char **mitems=NULL;
    mitems=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    mitems[i]=elems;

    va_list argP;
    va_start(argP, elems);

    char *p;
    for (i=1; ((p=va_arg(argP,char*)) !=NULL) ; i++ )
    {
        mitems=(char **)realloc(mitems,(i+1)*sizeof(char*));
        mitems[i]=p;
    }

    if (!p)
    {
        mitems=(char **)realloc(mitems,(i+1)*sizeof(char*));
        mitems[i]=NULL;
    }

    va_end(argP);
    /*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/

    (*mlabels)[j]->items=mitems;
    free(mitems);
}


int main()
{
    MenuLabels **ml;
    ml=ml_init();
    addit(&ml,"FILE","new","open","save","backup","print","setup","exit",NULL);
    addit(&ml,"AFILE","Anew","Asave","Abackup","Aexit",NULL);
    addit(&ml,"BFILE","Bnew","Bopen","Bsave","Bprint","Bexit",NULL);
    addit(&ml,"CFILE","Cnew","Copen","Csave","Cbackup","Cprint","Csetup","Cexit",NULL);
    addit(&ml,"DFILE","Dnew","Dsave","Dbackup","Dexit",NULL);
    addit(&ml,"EFILE","Enew","Eopen","Esave","Eprint","Eexit",NULL);


    printf("\n**********CHECK: %s",ml[3]->title);

for (int i=0;ml[i]!=NULL ;i++ )
    free(ml[i]);

    fprintf(stdout,"\n\033[1;91m***END***\033[0m\n");
    return 0;
}
```

@Some_programmer_dude, if not free mitems then there will be no more accessible memory allocated ...thank you all